# php oop traversing the parent::child relationship

Tags: php, oop, scope

my actual code is complex so here is a simple but relevant illustration:

```
class base {

  var $child1;
  var $child2;

  function xcv() {
    $this->child1 = new objChild1();
    $this->child2 = new objChild2();
  }
}

class objChild1 {
  var $fruit = "apple";
}

class objChild2 {
  function getChild1Fruit() {
    echo parent::child1->fruit;
  }
}
```

fairly straight forward but what if objGrandchild1 wants to call child2 etc...  is it like parent::parent::child1->fruit?

any tips in this area would be appreciated

===== EDIT =====
Sorry I just realised that ***parent*** belongs to the use of ***extend*** so probably nothing to do with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it right in the edit you made. An object has no realisation of the object that's being used in. You could get this reference through a parameter, though.

```
class base {

  var $child1;
  var $child2;

  function xcv() {
    $this->child1 = new objChild1();
    $this->child2 = new objChild2($this);
  }
}

class objChild1 {
  var $fruit = "apple";
}

class objChild2 {
  objChild2($parent) {
    $this->parent = $parent;
  }
  function getChild1Fruit() {
    echo $this->parent->child1->fruit;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes this is pretty much what i was after although i would have to alter my code significantly to accommodate the $this parameter. I assume this would work equally well with grandchildren? $this->parent->parent->child1->fruit. I am thinking though that i may be losing true OOP by going down this route. maybe i should pass $fruit as a var to objChild2

Comment: That would work equally well, yes. And I am not sure of your code structure, but from what I can see in the example, the use of `extends` would provide a better environment than passing variables around.